# Command line and argument processing

Tags: ruby, command-line, argv

Good morning...evening.

The problem is about calling method with given argument straightaway after typing in command line:

```
$ ruby my_class.rb someString
```

I have got a file my_class.rb with code:

```
class MyClass

  p ARGV

end
```

and that works, but I would like to use a method to print that input:

```
class MyClass

  def print_me(string)
    p string
  end

end
```

Is it even possible to do it without specifying class and method in command line and keep it that way?

```
$ ruby my_class.rb someString
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just define your class and then call it with the arguments like this:

```
class MyClass

  def print_me(string)
    p string
  end

end

MyClass.new.print_me(ARGV[0])
```

You can put the last line in a different file that requires your class definition. But this just changes how you manage your code.

Comment: The whole application now works. I wanted to keep it tidy in command line and now I can do it. Thank you very much.